# Configure SMTP Server to send mail

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp, windows-server-2012-r2

I have deployed a website (ASP.Net/C#) on my windows server 2012 R2 (it's a VPS and I installed IIS and SMTP), and everything works fine except one thing: I CANNOT send mail through my website!

I searched and tried everything but it still doesn't work! When I was debugging my application on local, it worked fine. Now I know I have to change my settings to send mail but I don't know what I should indicate

I'm sending my emails from a mail address that use pop3 server "relay.skynet.be" (this is the server I used when I was debugging and it worked) but when I do it on the website I got an error... So I changed it to the name of the server where my VPS is hosted (OVH) and it still doesn't work... I also changed the different credentials (in my code or in the SMTP in IIS) but the result is the same...

So I'm asking these questions:

- In my code (C#), what should I indicate?? Which server should I indicate? And which credentials?
- On Windows Server, in the SMTP settings in IIS, what should I choose? Should I indicate the e-mail address with which I send my emails? Do I have to check the "Use localhost" for the SMTP server to use or indicate the server of my mail address (relay.skynet.be) or the one from OVH? And for the credentials, what do I have to check? "Not required", "Windows" or "Specify Credentials" (with my mail address credentials?)

Comment: Do you have an exception message? It is very hard to debug an issue without know what error is being received. Simply saying "it doesn't work!" isn't particularly useful to anyone. You say it works when testing locally, but not from the server, this indicates it is a configuration issue - e.g. a port is blocked, or the SMTP doesn't trust the server the request is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a strong feeling that you are simply missing the infrastructure - specifically, you are missing an SMTP server. SMTP server is responsible for delivering (or forwarding) your email.

Neither POP3 nor IMAP protocols are used for sending emails.

If this is the case, I suggest you try using hotmail or gmail mail account. You can find the settings for both here, respectively:

http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-hotmail
http://www.serversmtp.com/en/smtp-gmail-configuration

Hope this helps.

Comment: I did it with a gmail address, even if that's not what I wanted to do, but thank you!

Comment: Is the problem that you need to send the email from a different sender email address?

Comment: Yes I want to send the email from another address than the gmail address ! I have the credentials (I put them in my code and it worked in localhost) but it doesn't work when I host my website

Comment: The question is whether your SMTP server, which works for you on localhost, is accesible from the web hosting site. It very well may only be accessible on your LAN. If that is the case, you need to use an appropriate SMTP server, which is accessible from the site where your web site resides. Your hosting provider will help you with that; your local IT support may also be able to provide you with server address which is accessible from outside.